# RPi3 + 3G USB Dongle. DHCPCD causes usb disconnect

Tags: usb, dhcp

I am working on a project using a RPi3 (OS: stretch) and a 3G dongle (usb stick). After 36 hours ish... my USB disconnects and I need to manually execute the "usb_modeswitch" command. As the pi should work remotely, I would like to know how to avoid this... In my syslog I have the following result:

dhcpcd: eth0: removing interface

and then all my usb ports got disconnected...

Do you know how to avoid this?

Your help would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't mind. Pity we seem to have lost the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Disable dhcpcd (remove it), and configure your network manually. A little effort and your system will run for months without trouble.